# How to use C++11 lambda as boost predicate?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, lambda

I want to split a `wstring` into a `vector<wstring>` using a single separator character.
This character is defined in a header file as a single `char`.
In order to keep the code clean and readable, I would really like to do this on a single line :)
I could not find a predicate to use, so I decided to use a C++11 lambda.

```
#include    <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include    <vector>
#include    <string>

constexpr char separator = '.';     // This is how it's declared in some header file

int main()
{
    std::wstring text( L"This.is.a.test" );

    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    // can't use is_any_of() unless i convert it to a wstring first.
    boost::algorithm::split( result, text, [](wchar_t ch) -> bool { return ch == (wchar_t) separator; });

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in a compilation error (clang 3.3):

```
clang++ -c -pipe -fPIC -g -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -I/usr/include -I/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang -I../splittest -I. -o debug/main.o ../splittest/main.cpp
In file included from ../splittest/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16:
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:148:13: error: non-type template argument refers to function 'failed' that does not have linkage
            BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/concept/assert.hpp:44:5: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT'
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT_FN(void(*)ModelInParens)
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:70:6: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT_FN'
    &::boost::concepts::requirement_<ModelFnPtr>::failed>    \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:146:40: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::iter_split<std::vector<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<wchar_t> > >, std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<<lambda at ../splittest/main.cpp:13:44> > >' requested here
            return ::boost::algorithm::iter_split(
                                       ^
../splittest/main.cpp:13:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::split<std::vector<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<wchar_t> > >, std::basic_string<wchar_t>, <lambda at ../splittest/main.cpp:13:44> >' requested here
    boost::algorithm::split( result, text, [](wchar_t ch) -> bool { return ch == (wchar_t) separator; });
                      ^
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:46:17: note: non-type template argument refers to function here
    static void failed() { ((Model*)0)->constraints(); }
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I doing something wrong or are C++11-lambdas not (completely?) supported in boost?

Is there another somehow readable single line solution?

I am currently using an own predicate `is_char()` which I defined in some base library, but I would rather get rid of it.

I know of boost lambdas (haven't used them, yet) - but should they really be used in C++11 code?

Thanks!

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2b2bcd429b500bc)

Comment: what version of boost ? Some of the older versions of boost are not compatible with c++11

Comment: it's boost 1.53. which version of boost and c++-compiler do you use, chris?

Comment: AFAIR, casting the lambda to a function pointer (which only works if it captures nothing, of course) worked for me.

Comment: I now tried with boost 1.55 & clang 3.3. Same problem. So I guess it must be clang. When I get the chance to test with clang 3.4 or 3.5, I will report the results here. (This might take some time.)

Comment: Not yet. I am reluctant to build clang on my own. So I'm waiting until I have to install a new linux system anyway. In the meantime, I used an old C++03 predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Out on a limb, try defining this before including the first boost header (beware of precompiled headers):

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```

Or - conversely

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1
```

I believe the defaults have changed. Recently. For specific compilers, so this could well explain it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this does not change anything.